# Не работает Update, хотя ошибки не выдает, таблица не обновляется

Tags: php, sql

Столкнулся с проблемой при попытке обновления таблицы. Запрос вроде бы идет и ошибок не показывает, но вот в таблице нет изменений. Я уже замучился искать ошибку. Хелп ми плиз!

1 Файл с методом:

```
public function update() {
$query = 'UPDATE Articles 
SET
title = :title,
img = :img,
descr = :descr,
shortdescr = :shortdescr,
authors = :authors,
dateart = :dateart
WHERE
id = :id';

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$id = $_POST["id"];
$tmp_file = $_FILES["user_image"]["tmp_name"];
$img_name = $_FILES["user_image"]["name"];
$title_key = $_POST["title"];
$descr_key = $_POST["descr"];
$short_descr = $_POST["shortdescr"];
$authors_key = $_POST["authors"];
$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); 

$this->title = $title_key;
$this->descr = $descr_key;
$this->img = $img_name;
$this->shortdescr = $short_descr;
$this->authors = $authors_key;
$this->dateart = $date;
$this->id = $id;

$upload_dir = "./artimages/".$img_name;
move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $upload_dir);

//Проверка на теги и html
$this->title = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->title));
$this->img = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->img));
$this->descr = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->descr));
$this->shortdescr = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->shortdescr));
$this->authors = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->authors));
$this->dateart = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->dateart));
$this->id = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));





//Bind data
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $this->title);
$stmt->bindParam(':img', $this->img);
$stmt->bindParam(':descr', $this->descr);
$stmt->bindParam(':shortdescr', $this->shortdescr);
$stmt->bindParam(':authors', $this->authors);
$stmt->bindParam(':dateart', $this->dateart);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);

if($stmt->execute()){
return true;
}

//Вывод ошибки в случае косяка

printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);

return false;
}
```

2 файл:

```
С вызовом update()

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content- 
Type, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, origin, accept');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: OPTIONS');
include_once '../../config/Database.php';
include_once '../../models/Post_article.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->connect();

$post = new Post($db);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$post->id = $data->id;
$post->title = $data->title;
$post->img = $data->img;
$post->descr = $data->descr;
$post->shortdescr = $data->shortdescr;
$post->authors = $data->authors;
$post->dateart = $data->dateart;

if($post->update()){
   echo json_encode(
   array('message' => 'UPDATED')
);
} else {
   echo json_encode(
   array('message' => 'NOT UPDATED')
);
}
```

Comment: учитесь отлаживать код. Хотя бы через `var_dump`

Comment: Я обнаружил, что у меня $_POST["title"] и другие POST-ты = null. Только теперь еще больше не знаю, что делать.